# Error message 'java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)'

Tags: android, json

I get the error message

> java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

when I try to apply the code below. This is the function I call and gives me this exception.

```
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    URL myurl = null;

    try {
        myurl = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/list.JSON");
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        URLConnection myconn = myurl.openConnection();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(myconn.getInputStream());
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line=br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I enter here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        jsoncode = sb.toString();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    threading = true;
    super.run();
}
```

[LogCat](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file):

```
06-30 11:33:21.457: W/System.err(619): java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
06-30 11:33:21.467: W/System.err(619):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:573)
06-30 11:33:21.467: W/System.err(619):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
06-30 11:33:21.479: W/System.err(619):     at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:663)
06-30 11:33:21.479: W/System.err(619):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:807)
06-30 11:33:21.479: W/System.err(619):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:77)
06-30 11:33:21.479: W/System.err(619):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
06-30 11:33:21.479: W/System.err(619):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
06-30 11:33:21.479: W/System.err(619):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
06-30 11:33:21.479: W/System.err(619):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
06-30 11:33:21.487: W/System.err(619):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
06-30 11:33:21.487: W/System.err(619):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
06-30 11:33:21.497: W/System.err(619):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
06-30 11:33:21.497: W/System.err(619):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
06-30 11:33:21.497: W/System.err(619):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
06-30 11:33:21.497: W/System.err(619):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
06-30 11:33:21.497: W/System.err(619):     at com.apk.PItestActivity$connection.run(PItestActivity.java:190)
06-30 11:33:21.507: W/System.err(619): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
06-30 11:33:21.517: W/System.err(619):     at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
06-30 11:33:21.517: W/System.err(619):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:169)
06-30 11:33:21.527: W/System.err(619):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:558)
06-30 11:33:21.527: W/System.err(619):     ... 15 more
```

And this is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.apk"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></permission>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".PItestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="addfriend"></activity>
        <activity android:name="updateDetails"></activity>
        <activity android:name="Details"></activity>
        <activity android:name="updateimage"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you checking with Device or Emulator?

Comment: You're trying to us a port number < 1024 and you don't have root permission.

Comment: i'm using port number 5200

Comment: Did you have any other application which run on port 5200 ? You can try some higher random number to test. As you are not able to create socket with desired port. Try with some other port.

Answer (score 379):

Try with,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

instead of,

```
<permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></permission>
```

Comment: +1. Also, albeit this has nothing to do with the actual problem, but: don't forget to install the *right* apk after you make this change... I've tricked myself by keeping another copy of the .apk in a distinct directory and forgot to overwrite it with the new one before installing from there.

Comment: Worked for me as of nov, 2013. Using eclipse, you can edit the AndroidManifest.xml with the fancy editor that has a Permissions tab. Add a Uses Permission and pick this permission from the dropdown menu.

Comment: important - the uses-permission tag needs to be before the application tag in  the manifest file. thats what fixed it for me at least..

Answer (score 41):

Try this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

And your `activity names`must be like this with `capital letters`:

```
<activity android:name=".Addfriend"/>
    <activity android:name=".UpdateDetails"/>
    <activity android:name=".Details"/>
    <activity android:name=".Updateimage"/>
```

Comment: - If you have additional information in answer, then only post if you have same as already answered then support that answer.

Comment: @user370305 excuse me, do you mean that he should only post the additional information? not being native, I cannot figure out what you meant but I'd like to know about meta stuff.

Answer (score 30):

Try adding the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 20):

Try moving `<uses-permission>` outside the `<application>` tag.

Answer (score 11):

**Uninstalling the app** on device and **then reinstalling** fixed it for me.

Tried all the other options, nothing. Finally found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266801/java-net-socketexception-socket-failed-eperm-operation-not-permitted). This is after adding permission (below) and cleaning build.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

try to add the following permission :
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an emulator for testing then you must use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`only and ignore `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`.It's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add those source code to your Java file as below:

```
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork().penaltyLog().build());
```

Comment: This is not the answer to this question which is about missing permission in manifest. And this is a very bad answer to the problem it is an answer to, i.e. `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do AndroidStudio - Build - Clean

If you updated manifest through the filesystem or Git it won't pick up the changes.