# Android Java App - java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

Tags: java, android, socketexception, adk

Using MYSQL for my android app:

MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button login;
EditText username, password;
TextView status;
HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setup();
}

private void setup() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
    login.setOnClickListener(this); 
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.login:

        login();

        break;
    }
    }

private void login() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        httpclient= new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://109.74.245.109/~profiled/android/index.php"); 
    //  Adding Data:
        nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    //  Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username.getText().toString().trim()));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password.getText().toString().trim()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    // Execute HTTP Post Request
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);



        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        status.setText(""+response);
        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("No user found")) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserPage.class));
        }


        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my error:

```
05-17 13:39:25.309: W/System.err(292): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
05-17 13:39:25.318: W/System.err(292):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocketImpl(Native Method)
05-17 13:39:25.318: W/System.err(292):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocket(OSNetworkSystem.java:186)
05-17 13:39:25.318: W/System.err(292):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:265)
05-17 13:39:25.318: W/System.err(292):  at java.net.Socket.checkClosedAndCreate(Socket.java:873)
05-17 13:39:25.318: W/System.err(292):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1020)
05-17 13:39:25.333: W/System.err(292):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
05-17 13:39:25.337: W/System.err(292):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
05-17 13:39:25.337: W/System.err(292):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-17 13:39:25.337: W/System.err(292):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-17 13:39:25.337: W/System.err(292):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
05-17 13:39:25.337: W/System.err(292):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-17 13:39:25.337: W/System.err(292):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-17 13:39:25.337: W/System.err(292):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-17 13:39:25.337: W/System.err(292):  at com.profiledt.helloworld.MainActivity.login(MainActivity.java:88)
05-17 13:39:25.337: W/System.err(292):  at com.profiledt.helloworld.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:70)
05-17 13:39:25.337: W/System.err(292):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-17 13:39:25.337: W/System.err(292):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-17 13:39:25.337: W/System.err(292):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-17 13:39:25.337: W/System.err(292):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-17 13:39:25.357: W/System.err(292):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-17 13:39:25.357: W/System.err(292):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-17 13:39:25.357: W/System.err(292):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 13:39:25.357: W/System.err(292):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-17 13:39:25.357: W/System.err(292):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-17 13:39:25.357: W/System.err(292):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-17 13:39:25.357: W/System.err(292):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't fully understand the error, but with it being permissions I have come to a few conclusions:

- It cannot connect to the mysql database
- Something to do with IP address and my server?

Comment: Do you have INTERNET permission set in your manifest file? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: Hi Mateusz, I've added what the people below have suggested. Still not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message 'java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273197/error-message-java-net-socketexception-socket-failed-eacces-permission-denie)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your manifest and check.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Why Access network state? it requres an internet permission not network state to acesss the interet

Comment: Hi, I added this to activity_main.xml and The application won't run and I'm getting this:

a LOT of errors: http://pastebin.com/xZSAtnj6

Comment: You need to add this to AndroidMainfest.xml

Comment: Hey Juned, I added it to my AndroidManifest.xml underneath <manifest/> and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: <manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>

Answer (score 2):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_INTERNET"/>
```

Also i have written a library that can help you do this in a different thread as opposed to what you are doing( running requests in the UI thread).

Maybe you will like it. if not there are other options out there

https://github.com/darko1002001/android-rest-client

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

There are 2 components at play usually. you don't connect to the Database directly, but rather you create a PHP script in your case which will connect to the database and act as a WebService which can accept requests and return JSON for example. THe android app acts as a client which calls your PHP webservice which connects to the database, reads and returns results.

so you have:

client(android) <-> Web service (PHP) <-> MySql Database

android doesn't go straight to the database.

A simple test would be the PC browser. if you enter your full url and press enter in a browser you should get the same exact response as you did that on android.

That means you have performed a GET request to your web service as all browser-enter actions are.

In your case it seems you are doing a POST request.

Read some artices on REST web services to get more info on how this is supposed to be setup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi DArkO, I'm still somewhat new to all this, will this allow me to connect to a mysql database and echo out all the information?

Thanks

Comment: Hey DArkO, that's what I've been doing :) Thanks