# Telnet client for Cisco switch using Android java apps

Tags: java, android, telnet, cisco, eclipse-luna

I am trying to write an Android apps as telnet client for cisco switch(2960) using apache.commons.net.telnet. But i have problem for connection. No output displayed on android emulator, but ConnectBot is running on the same emulator and can telnet to the switch perfectly. Here is code sample:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android2switch;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.EchoOptionHandler;
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.InvalidTelnetOptionException;
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.SuppressGAOptionHandler;
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetOptionHandler;
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TerminalTypeOptionHandler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;
    TextView textview;
    EditText edit1;
    Editable server;
    static TelnetClient telnetClient = new TelnetClient();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    setOptionHandlers();
                    //telnetClient.connect("192.168.0.1");
                    edit1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
                    server = edit1.getEditableText();
                    telnetClient.connect(server.toString());

                    read();
                    telnetClient.disconnect();
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
              }});      
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private static void setOptionHandlers() throws IOException {
        ArrayList<TelnetOptionHandler> optionHandlers = new ArrayList<TelnetOptionHandler>();
        optionHandlers.add(new TerminalTypeOptionHandler("VT100", false, false, true, false));
        optionHandlers.add(new EchoOptionHandler(true, false, true, false));
        optionHandlers.add(new SuppressGAOptionHandler(true, true, true, true));
        for (TelnetOptionHandler handler : optionHandlers) {
            try {
                telnetClient.addOptionHandler(handler);
            }
            catch (InvalidTelnetOptionException e) {
                System.err.println("Error registering option handler " + handler.getClass().getSimpleName());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void write(byte[] data) throws IOException {
        telnetClient.getOutputStream().write(data);
        telnetClient.getOutputStream().flush();
    }

    public void read() throws IOException {

        TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv1.setText("Read");
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        if((read = telnetClient.getInputStream().read(buff)) > 0) {
            tv1.append(new String(buff));
        }
        tv1.append("read="+read);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
tools:context="com.example.android2switch.MainActivity" >

<EditText
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/edit1"
android:hint="Command"
android:text="ip address" />
<Button
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:text="Run Program"
android:id="@+id/button1" />
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat

```
06-10 00:35:52.976: E/Trace(1938): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-10 00:35:53.716: D/libEGL(1938): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
06-10 00:35:53.716: D/libEGL(1938): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
06-10 00:35:53.716: D/libEGL(1938): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
06-10 00:35:53.726: D/(1938): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8c6d868, tid 1938
06-10 00:35:53.887: W/EGL_emulation(1938): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-10 00:35:53.906: D/OpenGLRenderer(1938): Enabling debug mode 0
06-10 00:36:26.367: W/EGL_emulation(1938): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-10 00:36:39.556: D/AndroidRuntime(1938): Shutting down VM
06-10 00:36:39.556: W/dalvikvm(1938): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3df9288)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:182)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:203)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:296)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at com.example.android2switch.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:45)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-10 00:36:39.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1938):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm completely new to Android development(Eclipse Luna) and i can't find any references/examples of android base telnet client for cisco switch/router.
Any references, sample code or guidances will be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error message 'java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273197/error-message-java-net-socketexception-socket-failed-eacces-permission-denie)

Comment: @HoboSapiens i'm still having problems with "error opening trace file" and "fatal exception main". Any similar example projects, sample code, references,  or guidances will be much appreciated, thank you Sir!

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the correct permissions to your manifest file? 
Make sure you have added the permission that allows applications to open network sockets.

```
"<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

see here for the details:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Also, similar problem was resolved here: [Error message 'java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273197/error-message-java-net-socketexception-socket-failed-eacces-permission-denie)

Comment: @Fund3burk ; thanks for ur fast reply and suggestion/references. I added the permissions and ran into new exception "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException".  there is no error in eclipse, only on logcat and i'm not sure if i writing the code right. what should i do?

Comment: You are attempting to run a networking operation in your main thread. This will cause the error you are experiencing. You can get around this by running your code in `AsyncTask`. Check the api here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Also, found another similar problem that was resolved.  If you're new, it may take some time to get this all figured out, but you're on your way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: implementing AsyncTask into my coding seem took forever because i'm having hard times to understand it, even i'm still struggling with my own code without referring to similar examples. tq n i will take ur advice to configure it myself but sadly time is a luxury that i dont have.