# Why I cannot connect android and PC through socket?

Tags: java, android, c++, sockets, tcp

I just started my first android application and have some troubles. I already have server code written in C++ in Qt. Since now I was using another console application as a client and everything works correctly. Now I'm trying to make a client part on my android (Android Studio). I want the client to be connected when I'll press the button. Only connection - no data exchange etc. When client (android) will be connected server should display communicate. 
Here is how my server connecting func. looks like:

```
 SUCCESSFUL = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,1), &WinSockData);
 sock_CONNECTION= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
 memset(& ADDRESS, 0, sizeof(ADDRESS));
 ADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
 ADDRESS.sin_family = AF_INET;
 ADDRESS.sin_port = htons(9090);

void Server::Connect()
{
bind(sock_CONNECTION, (SOCKADDR*)&ADDRESS, sizeof(ADDRESS));
listen(sock_CONNECTION,1);
SOCKET accept_Socket =0;
while(accept_Socket==0)
{
    accept_Socket = accept(sock_CONNECTION, NULL, NULL);
}
std::cout << "Client connected" << std::endl;
sock_CONNECTION=accept_Socket;
}
```

**UPDATE:** /I changed IP as you said in a comment/

Client's code. There are no fatal errors, just application is doing nothing. 
Code:

```
Socket socket;
  public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    socket = new Socket("192.168.0.227", 9090);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Errors:

```
Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaa23f380, error=EGL_SUCCESS
java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:619)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:198)
    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:584)
    at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:128)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
    at com.example.nataliah.client_testapp.Client_Connection$1.onClick(Client_Connection.java:26)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:282)
   at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:604)
```

**UPDATE 2** After adding permission to network I received those errors + the old ones:

```
android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
                                                                                       at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
                                                                                       at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
                                                                                       at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
                                                                                       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
                                                                                       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:163)
```

Comment: That is because, `127.0.0.1` is the IP address of localhost. Edit the address of your PC in the Java Code.

Comment: also, kindly add your stack trace, while asking questions.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I understand the problem but I still don't know on which address I should change it...

Comment: First things first. Add your stack trace.

Comment: I edited post and added errors.

Comment: Are u sure, your update 2 has full stack trace ?

Answer (score 1):

[Most probably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273197/error-message-java-net-socketexception-socket-failed-eacces-permission-denie) your application does not have permissions necessary to access the network. Try adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

inside the `<manifest>` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`