# Jain SIP error when creating listening point

Tags: java, android, sip, jain-sip

I'm trying to run the Jain-SIP example application in Android, found here: https://github.com/usnistgov/jsip/blob/master/src/examples/android/simplecallsetup/Shootist.java

The code returns an error when it tries to create a listening point at the following line

```
udpListeningPoint = sipStack.createListeningPoint("127.0.0.1", 5060, transport);
```

The code can be found on the github page linked above.

### **Do you know what might be causing the error?**

The example given on the github for java works fine in IntelliJ.
I'm using the following dependency for Jain-SIP:

```
compile group: 'javax.sip', name: 'android-jain-sip-ri', version: '1.3.0-91'
```

### I'm using Android Studio with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

My MainActivity class is as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Shootist().init();
    }
}
```

The entire error output is below

```
07/23 15:30:37: Launching app
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.jainsiptestapplication/com.example.jainsiptestapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 23998 on device Pixel_2_API_29 [emulator-5554]
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/testapplicatio: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
I/chatty: uid=10154(com.example.jainsiptestapplication) identical 10 lines
W/testapplicatio: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
W/testapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/testapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/System.err: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (shootist).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
I/System.out: createSipStack android.gov.nist.javax.sip.SipStackImpl@226a293
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/System.out: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
W/System.err: android.javax.sip.InvalidArgumentException: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at android.gov.nist.javax.sip.SipStackImpl.createListeningPoint(SipStackImpl.java:1677)
        at com.example.jainsiptestapplication.Shootist.init(Shootist.java:280)
        at com.example.jainsiptestapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7783)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7772)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at android.gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.UDPMessageProcessor.<init>(UDPMessageProcessor.java:169)
        at android.gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.OIOMessageProcessorFactory.createMessageProcessor(OIOMessageProcessorFactory.java:46)
        at android.gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPTransactionStack.createMessageProcessor(SIPTransactionStack.java:2509)
        at android.gov.nist.javax.sip.SipStackImpl.createListeningPoint(SipStackImpl.java:1657)
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:662)
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.datagramSocketCreate(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:197)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.create(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:93)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.createImpl(DatagramSocket.java:357)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:259)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:319)
W/System.err:     at android.gov.nist.core.net.DefaultNetworkLayer.createDatagramSocket(DefaultNetworkLayer.java:98)
        at android.gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.UDPMessageProcessor.<init>(UDPMessageProcessor.java:144)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at libcore.io.Linux.socket(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.socket(ForwardingOs.java:217)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:370)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.socket(ForwardingOs.java:217)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:658)
        ... 27 more
I/System.out: java examples.shootist.Shootist 
    >>>> is your class path set to the root?
I/testapplicatio: System.exit called, status: 0
I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
Application terminated.
```

Comment: It appears to be working fine now. I believe what solved it was uninstalling and reinstalling the app on the emulator.

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582336/permission-for-sockets-android-manifest?noredirect=1&lq=1