# android studio emulator not working(Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1")

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I tried emulator with my acitivity but continuously getting this error message.

```
11/14 15:48:10: Launching 'app' on Nexus 5X API 29.
$ adb shell am start -n "org.techtown.loginactivity/org.techtown.loginactivity.LoginActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for process to come online...
Connected to process 25712 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Process 25712 terminated.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/n.loginactivit: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
W/n.loginactivit: Verification of void org.techtown.loginactivity.LoginActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) took 197.934ms
D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:183): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=7421 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c134,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
```

I had no idea how to  run ordinarily..

Comment: Any clues on solution for this? Am hitting same wall here :)

Comment: hitting the same here. @jeong06090navercom please advise on how you solved it

Answer (score 1):

Solved for me:

Removed application from an emulator and install again solved my problem, thanks. Seems that firebase cache something to the filesystem and reuse it, I suppose clear application data also will solve a problem. – Onregs Sep 12 '19 at 8:47

[java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266801/java-net-socketexception-socket-failed-eperm-operation-not-permitted)