# Cleartext HTTP traffic to my localhost is not permitted

Tags: android, http, android-volley

I'm using Volley for a GET request to an address on my localhost, but it fails with the error:

```
Cleartext HTTP traffic to 192.168.1.45 not permitted
```

I followed the guide here: [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)
And did the following:

Created the network security xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://192.168.1.45/companyweb/greetings</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Added it in my manifest and also allowed cleartext traffic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.omerfaran.myudemyapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

I'm still getting the same error. Changing from 'http' to 'https' gives this error:

```
socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

My code in MainActivity:

```
val url = "http://192.168.1.45/companyweb/greetings"
val rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
val sr = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener { response ->
    fragmentText.text = response
    Log.d("TAG", "success")
}, Response.ErrorListener { error -> Log.d("TAG", "fail" + error.toString()) })
rq.add(sr)
```

What can I do next?

Comment: `192.168.1.45` is not localhost

Comment: But it's my IP isn't it? the url works in my browser

Comment: What is "my" ip? Every device has its own ip. Pc, Android device, laptop... So where are you talking about? What is "my" browser? On every device can run one or more browsers. So of which one are you talking?

Answer (score 3):

You should include only the IP address, that is:

```
<domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.45</domain>
```

Comment: It's not working, when I try I get the error: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Comment: I think it's the same as changing http to https?

Comment: Oh I found the answer, I had to just restart the emulator....You were right about your suggestion, it's actually the same as changing to https in this case, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in a recent project, try adding:

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

To your AndroidManifext.xml file under the application tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
[java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266801/java-net-socketexception-socket-failed-eperm-operation-not-permitted)

Apparantly what I had to do is restart the emulator (or uninstall the app)