# No response from PokeAPI

Tags: android-volley

I am trying to get JSONObject from the Pokeapi in my Pokedex app, but it seems that there is no response and the volley error is produced. However, the link opens perfectly fine in my browser showing the JSON. I tried different links to the JSON, still it does not work. Permission to use internet is added to AndroidManifest. Request is added to RequestQueue. Where could be the problem?

Here is my PokedexAdapter class:

```
package com.example.pokedex;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PokedexAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PokedexAdapter.PokedexViewHolder> {
    public static class PokedexViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public LinearLayout containerView;
        public TextView textView;

        PokedexViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            containerView = view.findViewById(R.id.pokedex_row);
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.pokedex_row_text_view);

            containerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Pokemon current = (Pokemon) containerView.getTag();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PokemonActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", current.getName());
                    //intent.putExtra("number", current.getNumber());

                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private List<Pokemon> pokemon = new ArrayList<>();
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;

    public PokedexAdapter(Context context) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        loadPokemon();
    }

    public void loadPokemon() {
        String url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray("results");
                            for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);
                                pokemon.add(new Pokemon(
                                        result.getString("name"),
                                        result.getString("url")));
                            }

                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e("cs50", "onResponse: ", e);
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("cs50", "onErrorResponse: pokemon list error");
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PokedexViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.pokedex_row, parent, false);
        return new PokedexViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PokedexViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Pokemon current = pokemon.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(current.getName());
        holder.containerView.setTag(current);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pokemon.size();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pokedex">    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".PokemonActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Result - nothing is shown on the screen and this error is produced:

2020-06-09 19:09:37.469 15137-15137/com.example.pokedex D/cs50: onErrorResponse: pokemon list error

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by reinstalling the app.

This thread was helpful: 
[java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266801/java-net-socketexception-socket-failed-eperm-operation-not-permitted)